# prototype for function does not match any in class C++

Tags: c++

I keep getting an error that says "prototype for 'void Engine::start(Tank&)' does not match any in class 'Engine'" Additionally, it says "'Tank' has not been declared," all of which are at the same function 'start' in the Engine class.

```
    //Engine.h
    #ifndef ENGINE_H
    #define ENGINE_H

    using namespace std;

    class Engine {
    public:
         Engine(int);
         ~Engine() {};
         void setTrip(int tr);
         int getTrip();
         bool isStarted();
         void start(Tank &inTank);
         void stop();
     protected:
         bool started;
         int trip, numCyl;
     };

     #endif /* ENGINE_H */

    //Engine.cpp
    using namespace std;

    #include "Engine.h"
    #include "Tank.h"
```

there is more to this .cpp but this is the function where the error is 
happening.

```
    void Engine::start(Tank &inTank) {
           if(inTank.isEmpty()) {
                 cout << "Engine cannot start\n";
                 started = false;
           }
           else {
                 cout << "Engine started\n";
                 started = true;
           }
     }
```

and my main here is used for testing these two classes.

```
    #include "Tank.h"
    #include "Engine.h"
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
         Tank t(12);
         Engine e(4);
         e.start(t);
         e.stop();
         t.refuel();
         e.start(t);
         e.stop();
         return 0;
     }
```

and I'll add my Tank class.

```
    #ifndef TANK_H
    #define TANK_H

    using namespace std;

    class Tank {
          public:
               Tank(float);
               virtual ~Tank();
               void consumeFuel(float);
               float getFuel();
               virtual void refuel();
               bool isEmpty();
               int getNumTanks();
               float getTankCapacity();
               void setFuel(float fl);
          protected:
               static int numTanks;
               const float tankCapacity;
               float fuel;
               bool empty;
          };

          #endif    /* TANK_H */
```

Tank.cpp

```
     using namespace std;

     #include "Tank.h"
     #include "Engine.h"

     //creates tank with certain capacity taken from parameter.
     Tank::Tank(float inCap) {
            Tank::tankCapacity(inCap);
     }

     //I completed the rest of the functions with no errors... so far.lul
```

Comment: Looks like `Engine.h` doesn't include `Tank.h`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever class is being used by Reference or Pointer in header, than you need to forward declare that class rather than including entire .h file.

So in your case, you just need to forward declare class Tank in Engine.h and include Tank.h in Engine.cpp.

```
    //Engine.h
    #ifndef ENGINE_H
    #define ENGINE_H

    //Forward Declaration
    class Tank;

    using namespace std;

    class Engine {
    public:
         Engine(int);
         ~Engine() {};
         void setTrip(int tr);
         int getTrip();
         bool isStarted();
         void start(Tank &inTank);
         void stop();
     protected:
         bool started;
         int trip, numCyl;
     };

     #endif /* ENGINE_H */
```

Comment: I'm assuming it's the check mark. It is now green. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Move the Tank class declaration above the Engine class

Comment: I think OP might have them in separate files.

Comment: then in your Engine.cpp add a #include"Tank.h" or forward declare Tank class in Engine.h using `class Tank;`

Comment: it looks like that already happens. see my comment on the OP for the actual problem.